# How do I remove el7 and it's packages on CentOS 6.9?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, putty, centos-6

I'm trying to install Centreon from ssh and I got this error:

```
Error: Package: centreon-clib-1.4.2-3.el7.centos.x86_64 (centreon-stable)
   Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: centreon-connector-ssh-1.1.2-3.el7.centos.x86_64 (centreon-stable)
   Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: centreon-connector-ssh-1.1.2-3.el7.centos.x86_64 (centreon-stable)
   Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: centreon-clib-1.4.2-3.el7.centos.x86_64 (centreon-stable)
   Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: What did you do to install it?

Comment: Repository install

Comment: Unfortunately I installed CentOS 7 repo for noob and I can't remove it